# Is there a simple way to get the RMS of a range in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a simple direct way to calculate the root mean square / quadratic mean in google sheets? I'd rather not have to create another array with squares of the first one in order to sum the squares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without you giving any further information about what your data looks like you can do the following

Assume you have data like this

```
   A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

You can use an arrayformula to get the RMS

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SQRT(AVERAGE(A1:C3^2)))
```

Answer (score 10):

One way to do it is to use SUMSQ.

Assuming your array is `A1:A4`, the RMS would be

`SQRT(SUMSQ(A1:A4)/COUNT(A1:A4))`